# Isomorphism of quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In a course on algebraic number theory, the lecturer says

> $$\mathcal{O}_K\cong \mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2}\right] \cong\frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)}.$$

This means, for a prime $p\in \mathbb Z$, we have

$$\frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{p\mathcal{O}_K}\cong \frac{\mathbb F_p[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)}.$$

When I tried to justify this claim, I found up a theorem from a course I took on group theory (the [third isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem)) which said that if $G$ is a group with $L, K \unlhd G$, $K\leq L$ then

$$\frac{G}{L} \cong \frac{G/K}{L/K}$$

and thought about what the right generalization of this would be for rings. I think in my case it would be

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{p\mathcal{O}_K} &\cong \left. \frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)} \middle/ p\left(\frac{ \mathbb Z[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)}\right) \right.\\
&\cong \frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{p\mathbb Z[x]}
\end{align*}

What am I doing wrong? Does the result for groups not generalize to rings? Have I made a silly mistake?

Comment: The result indeed generalizes to rings and ideals, but there is a problem in the way you have it set up: (x^2-x-(d-1)/4) is not a subset of pZ[x], so the quotient you have in the denominator makes no sense.

Comment: I see. How would I get the correct result then, if not using this? I think I'm having difficulty understanding what I can do with an expression like $p\mathcal O _K$

Comment: Perhaps I have something: \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{p\mathcal{O}_K} &\cong \left. \frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)} \middle/ p\frac{ \mathbb Z[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)} \right.\\
&\cong \left. \frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{\left( x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4} \right)} \middle/ (\vphantom{\frac{1}{1}}p) \right.
\end{align*} And then using a result I hope is true: $$\frac{R/I}{J} \cong \frac{R/J}{I} $$ would get there?

Comment: Again, your symbols on that last line are not quite making sense. The ideal you want to consider is I+J = (x^2-x-(d-1)/4, p). You can form third isomorphism quotients in two different ways.

Comment: @James How do you get the last isomorphism you claim? in particular

$$p\left({\Bbb Z[x]\over \left(x^2-x-{d-1\over 4}\right)}\right)\ne p\Bbb Z[x]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the isomorphism theorem you're quoting **is** true for rings as well as groups, you just assume $I\subseteq J\subseteq R$ and $I,J$ are ideals. Then

> $$R/I\bigg/ J/I\cong R/J$$

Now what are the ideals in your case and what's the ring? Well $R=\Bbb Z[x]$, $J=\left(p,x^2-x-{d-1\over 4}\right)$ and $I_1=(p), I_2=\left(x^2-x-{d-1\over 4}\right)$.

Then since we have

> $$\Bbb F_p[x]/\left(x^2-x-{d-1\over 4}\right)\cong R/I_1\bigg/ J/I_1\cong R/J\cong R/I_2\bigg/ J/I_2\cong \mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K$$

we can conclude the result you're looking for.